# jQueryMobile - Change size of only a few buttons

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, button

I have several buttons across multiple 'pages' in jQueryMobile. I'm able to change the size of all buttons using the following in my css.

```
.ui-btn { 
    height: 150px; 
}
```

However, I only want the buttons to be this large (150px) on my first page (id='menu') and the other pages should have the default height value.  I tried `#menu .ui-btn {...}` and adding a class bigButton and doing `.bigButton .ui-btn {...}` but that didn't work either.

```
<div data-role="page" id="menu">
    <div data-role="content">
        <button id="snapPic" class="bigButton" onclick="capturePhoto();">Snap picture</button> 
        <br/>
        <button id="makeClouds" class="bigButton" onclick="location.href='makeClouds.html'">Make clouds</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you use `<a>` instead of `<button>` by adding `data-role="button"`, it will be easier to modify and both give the same results. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/eYpUK/

Comment: great, that fixed it -- thx. I can accept answer if you put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 and below

Add `data-role="button`" to anchor tag to convert it into a button. And then apply your own styles.

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" class="bigButton">Big Button</a>
```

#### [jQuery Mobile 1.4 (Beta)](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0-beta.1/demos/button-markup/)

For performance purposes, `data-role="button"` is removed now and replaced with class `.ui-btn`.

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn bigButton">Big Button</a>
```